# marklogic MLCP import fail due to time limit exceeded

Tags: marklogic

How can I avoid "time limit exceeded" when use MLCP import zip files.

```
18/07/02 10:39:19 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
18/07/02 10:39:19 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input 
paths to process : 12
18/07/02 10:39:22 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 0%
18/07/02 10:41:53 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 8%
18/07/02 10:42:16 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 17%
18/07/02 10:42:38 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 25%
18/07/02 10:42:43 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 33%
18/07/02 10:44:09 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 42%
18/07/02 10:44:49 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner:  completed 50%
18/07/02 10:52:47 ERROR mapreduce.ContentWriter: SVC-EXTIME: Time limit exceeded
18/07/02 10:56:55 WARN mapreduce.ContentWriter: Failed document /R10/3F_7_3600_PaB_2010.xml
```

Comment: Can you post the options that you are using for the MLCP execution? Also, check the ErrorLog to see if there are any error, warn, or notice level messages around the time of ingest that might indicate an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with using `-transaction_size 1`, and `-batch_size 1`. That will cause batches to complete quicker. If you find your MarkLogic server running low on mem or cpu, consider also tuning down `-thread_count`.

You can also look into increasing the `default time limit` setting of the app server behind the MarkLogic port you are using for the upload, if tweaking the above parameters is insufficient.

HTH!